# Create a diagram based on user input on a website

Tags: web-apps, web-development, drawing, diagram

I want to create a diagram based on user input, that the user provided in a form of the webapplication. For example the user should enter every person that communicates with an eShop system. After that a diagram of that communication should be automatically created by the webapplication. It should look like in the picture below. [image: diagram that should be created from the webapplication]
How can I do this? Which technologies do I need to automatically draw a diagram in a webapplication based on user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Essential Diagram for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram) supports creating any kind of diagram with nodes and connectors.We have created an example in which we have positioned the nodes and connectors explicitly, but a similar diagram can be positioned dynamically as well.

[Example](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/u1w5wind)

[image: Diagram JS with animated connectors]

[Automatic Radial layout example](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/dlc3my2t)

[image: Diagram Radial layout]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.